# A Beginner’s Confusion about Screen Dimensions and Screen Density

Tags: java, android, screen, resolution

I’m very new to Android programming and the one thing that really has me confused relates to screen density and screen dimensions. I’ve read plenty of replies to other questions on here and I’ve read the Google docs on how to program for multiple screen sizes. None have really helped address either the problem or my own general ignorance. I hope it is okay to ask this here so somebody might finally explain it simply enough so that I’ll be able to wrap my brain around this problem.

First of all, I’ve been working with SurfaceViews onto which I’m throwing bitmaps. I’ve been primarily programming for the Samsung Note 10.1 (2014) edition. The screen is 2048x1536 and returns a screen density of 2.0 when I query the display. My approach has been to make graphics that work at those dimensions but within the code, I’ve used the oft-quoted formula to convert floating point dp coordinates into pixels, ready for the moment I move to other devices.

```
px = (dp * density) + 0.5f
```

I’ve now been trying to get the app working on a Samsung S2. The screen is 480 by 800.On the phone, the app is (I assume correctly) loading graphics from the HDPI folder because the pixel density is 1.5.

My first problem was that the graphics in the HDPI were originally far too big. I’d used the Resize program to quickly resize my original XHDPI folder. Perhaps I simply didn’t select the correct source setting but the resulting graphics where far bigger than the actual 480x800 graphic I finally found filled the screen.

However, that was only a symptom of my larger confusion.

When developing an app using bitmaps, is there some magic formula I’ve missed which allows dp values to be translated to pixels or should I be doing calculations based on the actual screen dimensions? By the formular, 100dp is approximately 150px on the (1.5 density) 800px wide screen but 200px on the bigger (2.0 density) 2560 display. That’s 18% horizontally across the S2’s screen but only 8% across the wider screen on the Note 10.1.

I naively assumed that a dp value would translate across all devices and simply put things in the right place or do I have that wrong? Just writing this up makes me even more convinced that I misunderstood what dp values are. I was confused by the suggestion of working to a theoretical Google device with a pixel density of 1 and then adapting everything based on other pixel densities or screen sizes.

Simply to say, as I keep hearing, work in dp unites so everything is uniform hasn’t quite worked for me so I’m now seeking the advice of wiser council. In other words: please help!

Thanks.

Comment: I've read it all and didn't quite get what exactly you want to know, what's the final question?

Comment: Perhaps that's my problem. I'm vaguely asking: when working with bitmaps, do we work based on the size of the screen or these dp values? I'm confused why we use them when they seem to give different relative positions on different screens. Or I'm simply using them wrong and need direction on how to use them correctly.